# Using jq to update objects within a JSON document if the value corresponding to a given key starts with a specified string

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have the given JSON and want to change the `id` value of all elements, which starts with `test` in the `name` element:

```
{
    "other-value": "some-id",
    "values": [
        {
            "name": "test-2017-12-01",
            "id": "1"

        },
        {
            "name": "othert",
            "id": "2"
        }

    ]
}
```

The following jq commands works [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/iqAiSq9Fui)

```
jq (.values[] | select(.name == "test-afs").id) |= "NEWID"
```

But when I try it with `startswith` it stops working, what am I missing? [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/_kpouHRemx)

```
(.values[] | select(.name | startswith("test")).id) |= "NEWID"
```

> jq: error (at :14): Invalid path expression near attempt to access element "id" of {"name":"test-afs","id":"id"}
>   exit status 5

Comment: Your proposal with `startswith` works now with `jq 1.6`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `map`, like this:

```
jq '(.values)|=(map((if .name|startswith("test") then .id="NEWID"  else . end)))' file
```

Output:

```
{
  "other-value": "some-id",
  "values": [
    {
      "name": "test-2017-12-01",
      "id": "NEWID"
    },
    {
      "name": "othert",
      "id": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @hek2mgl What should I do if I have an array and want to add a new value on the conditional basis?

Answer (score 3):

Please note that since the release of jq 1.5, jq has been enhanced to support the query that previously failed.  For example, using the current 'master' version:

```
jq -c '(.values[] | select(.name | startswith("test")).id) |= "NEWID"'
{"other-value":"some-id","values":[{"name":"test-2017-12-01","id":"NEWID"},{"name":"othert","id":"2"}]}
```

Using earlier versions of jq, if/then/else/end can be used in this type of situation as follows:

```
.values[] |= if .name | startswith("test") then .id = "NEWID" else . end
```

If using `map`, a minimalist expression would be:

```
.values |= map(if .name|startswith("test") then .id = "NEWID" else . end)
```

Comment: *enhanced* should be *fixed* ;)