# JDT transform to modify N-th array element

Tags: json, transform, slowcheetah

I am trying to apply a [JDT](https://github.com/microsoft/json-document-transforms) transform to a JSON document in order to modify a property in a N-th array element. Is that possible without having to replace the entire element or even the entire array?

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      name: "A",
      value: 0
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      value: 3.14
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a transform that gets me to the following? I want to alter the 2nd array element and only its "value" property. I don't want to search for it by "name" but rather access by index.

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      name: "A",
      value: 0
    },
    {
      name: "B",
      value: 12345678
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution yet? Or at least the confirmation that it might in principle work?

Comment: No. I'd post it here.

Answer (score 1):

### The challenge

It is easy to do your transform  with some libraries in JSON. If your object is called `foo`, you mainly want to something like `foo.array[1].value = "12345678"` without any kind of looping.

#### The JDT way

I found [How to use SlowCheetah to transform an array elements in Json config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47297274/8330162) which asks

> For example, if my base config file has this setting:
>
> ```
> {
>   "Settings" :  [1, 2, 3] 
> }
> ```
>
> and I want to transfer it to:
>
> ```
> {
>   "Settings" :  [4, 5, 6] 
> }
> ```

The solution by [Collin K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1369/collin-k) was

> ```
> {
>   "@jdt.replace": {
>     "@jdt.path": "$.Settings",
>     "@jdt.value": [4,5,6]
>   }
> }
> ```

**This seems like you need to actually replace the whole array.**

Digging further let me to an [open issue of JDT](https://github.com/microsoft/json-document-transforms/issues/23) which seems to confirm this assumption.

### Disclaimer

I have not used JDT myself, but I have been struggling with nested JSONs of various kinds e.g. with Elasticsearch.

### Further references

- https://github.com/microsoft/json-document-transforms/wiki/Replace-Transformation
- [Using jq to update objects within a JSON document if the value corresponding to a given key starts with a specified string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410394/) - the JQ way I would use

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this is not what I am after. I think the problem is described clearly. In your example, I want to replace element 3 with e.g. a 6 (not the entire array).

Comment: Something fully unrelated: What keyboard does your avantar show?

Comment: Haha. An interesting question. It's ZX Spectrum 48K. You have to be really old to know this. Unfortunately, your extensive answer doesn't solve the issue for me.

Comment: Np & thx. My first computer was a C64... But did I at least understood the issue correctly?